# Razor inline helper function accepts only <string> fields

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm trying to figure out a solution to remove a lot of duplication in my Razor View. The page contains a form that has many fields with almost identical wrappers and attributes.

The following works for string and int fields:

```
    <div class="col m-0 p-0">
        <div class="d-flex">
            <div class="d-flex w-100 form-group-sm m-0">
                @Html.LabelFor(x => x.ReportHeader.PropertyName)
                @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.ReportHeader.PropertyName)
            </div>
            <div class="invalid-feedback">Invalid</div>
            <div class="valid-feedback">Valid</div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

But my helper only works for string fields and I'm not sure how to make it generic. How do I modify the signature to allow calling with any type of field (string, int, etc)?

```
@helper DisplayFieldFor(
    Expression<Func<ReportCreateViewModel, string>> field, 
    string wrapperClass, 
    object htmlAttributes)
{
    <div class="col m-0 p-0">
        <div class="d-flex @Html.Raw(wrapperClass)">
            <div class="d-flex w-100 form-group-sm m-0">
                @Html.LabelFor(field, new { @class = "" })
                @Html.TextBoxFor(field, htmlAttributes)
            </div>
            <div class="invalid-feedback">Invalid</div>
            <div class="valid-feedback">Valid</div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

Example call to the helper (string property):

```
@DisplayFieldFor(m => m.ReportHeader.PropertyName, "d-flex w-100 form-group-sm m-0", new { @title = "This is an example help tooltip.", @class = "form-control-sm flex-grow-1", @placeholder = "Placeholder", @data_toggle = "tooltip", @data_placement = "top" })
```

All of this is rough and preliminary since I'm just feeling out if it's a clean solution.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this can be done with the `functions` syntax.

You will need to create an App_Code folder if you haven't already got one.

Then inside your App_Code folder create a file called DisplayFieldFor.cshtml, this will contain the code for your helper.  It is important this file is placed in the App_Code folder or it won't work.

Contents of DisplayFieldFor.cshtml

```
@using System.Linq.Expressions
@using System
@using System.Web.Mvc;
@using System.Web.Mvc.Html;

@functions
{    
    public static HelperResult DisplayForMyField<TModel, TItem>(
        HtmlHelper<TModel> html,
        Expression<Func<TModel, TItem>> expr,
        string wrapperClass,
        object htmlAttributes)
    {

        return RenderField(html.LabelFor(expr, new { @class = "" }), html.TextBoxFor(expr, htmlAttributes), wrapperClass);
    }
}
@helper RenderField(
    MvcHtmlString label,
    MvcHtmlString textBox,
    string wrapperClass)
{
    <div class="col m-0 p-0">
        <div class="d-flex @wrapperClass">
            <div class="d-flex w-100 form-group-sm m-0">
                @label
                @textBox
            </div>
            <div class="invalid-feedback">Invalid</div>
            <div class="valid-feedback">Valid</div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

In your normal view you can call your helper like this.

```
@DisplayFieldFor.DisplayForMyField(Html, m => m.ReportHeader.PropertyName, "d-flex w-100 form-group-sm m-0", new { @title = "This is an example help tooltip.", @class = "form-control-sm flex-grow-1", @placeholder = "Placeholder", @data_toggle = "tooltip", @data_placement = "top" })
```

Your code will now be generic for any property type as required.